# add periods to the end of string if it's longer than given argument

Tags: javascript, string, truncate

```
function truncate(str, num) {
  if(str.length < num) {
    return str;
  }
  else {
    str = str.slice(0, num);
    return str;
  }

}
truncate('A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket', 11);
//truncate('A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket', 'A-tisket a-tasket  
  A green and yellow basket'.length)
//truncate('A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket', 
 'A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket'.length + 2)
```

I need to have the code return 'A-tisket...' if the length of the string is longer than my num argument. When I run this code, it slices to 'A-tisket a-', how can I remove " a-" and add periods to the end when the length of string is longer than my num argument? I tried using .replace() method after .split() but cannot figure a way to replace it.

Comment: `else{return str.slice(0,num-3)+'…';}`?

Comment: @Rick Hitchcock edit: sorry, num length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok! Good news is, you essentially have it already.

If you want to add `...` to the end, you've just about got it - just change `return str` to `return str + "...";`

To ensure that we don't add `...` when `num` is equal to the string's length, we can simply change `<` to `<=`.

So that gives you:

```
function truncate(str, num) {
    if(str.length <= num) {
        return str;
    } else {
        str = str.slice(0, num);
        return str + "...";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
truncate('A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket', 11);
>>> "A-tisket a-..."

truncate('A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket',
    'A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket'.length);
>>> "A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket"

truncate('A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket',
    'A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket'.length + 2);
>>> "A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket"
```

Comment: @bhspencer  this will only pass only truncate('A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket', 11). I need other two function argument to pass as well.

Comment: @user4852194 Ok! What would the sample second argument be?

Comment: truncate('A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket', 'A-tisket a-tasket  
  A green and yellow basket'.length)
truncate('A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket', 
 'A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket'.length + 2) I need to pass these two arguments as well

Comment: @user4852194 Ok! updated my answer. That what you're looking for?

Comment: almost :( the first truncate argument needs to return 'A-tisket...' and the second truncate argument should not have '...' since the num argument is equal to string length. I think if statement needs to be if(str.length <= num)

Comment: @user4852194 got it - edited my answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

Just trim more characters off the end (to make room for the periods) and then add the periods to the return value string.

I would also recommend you use `<=` in your condition, otherwise you will end up adding dots when they are not needed.

Finally, for full resilience, you will want to ensure that you don't wrap around by 'slicing' with a negative length...

```
function truncate(str, num) {
    if (str.length <= num) {
        return str;
    } else {
        var append = "...";
        var remove = num - append.length;
        if (remove < 0) {
            remove = 0;
            append = append.slice(0, num);
        }
        str = str.slice(0, remove);
        return str + append;
    }
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6xr1wvc2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the + operator to concatenate the periods to the end of your string.

```
function truncate(str, num) {
  if(str.length < num) {
    return str;
  }
  else {
    str = str.slice(0, num);
    return str + "...";
  }
}
```